# iOS: performSegueWithIdentifier trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am pretty new to objective C and iOS, as I am primarily a C++/java developer and I cannot for the life of me get `performSegueWithIdentifier` to work properly or in other words, it wont move to the next segue. I am making a simple login system where I have a condition if the status code is not 401 or 403 then go to the main app. Currently in my storyboard I have my main view controller with my textFields and a button to login. I then made a segue from the `MainViewController` (not the button) with the Identifier `MoveToMainApp` and style `model`. in my implementation file for the main view controller I have the following methods:

```
-(void)moveToMainApp
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MoveToMainApp" sender:nil];
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    NSString *username = _usernameTxt.text;
    NSString *password = _passwordTxt.text;
    _errorLabel.text = @"";
    if(username.length > 0 && password.length > 0)
    {
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://samplesite.org/mobile_app"]];
        [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                path:@"http://samplesite.org/mobile_app/login.php"
                                                          parameters:@{@"username":username, @"password":password}];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // Print the response body in text
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
            if(statusCode == 401 || statusCode == 403)
            {
                _errorLabel.text = @"Invalid credentials";
            }
            else
            {
                [self moveToMainApp];
            }
        }];

        [operation start];
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's occurring? Is it breaking?

Comment: sorry should have made this clear, it is not moving to the next segue.

Comment: in order to accomplish a segue with storyboard you must control + drag from your login Controller to your destination controller and a popup window will appear with the name manual segue, just select modal, now select the segue in attributes inspector set an identifier for your segue then you can call your segue with [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" sender:self];

Comment: Also I have tried that and that does not work.

Comment: Is it definitely hitting the moveToMainApp call?
If it is I'm wondering if it's to do with it being in a block in a background queue, can you try this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self moveToMainApp];});`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a UINavigationController and push segues everywhere for easier viewController navigation. But for your current problem with modal segues, I am wondering if it is not transitioning because the segue goes from the view controller itself, rather than the button. Try creating a button and have the segue go from it to the next view controller, but have the button hidden, disabled, and in the corner so it can't be triggered by the user. So basically change the source from the view controller to a button. That is what I do when I want a segue, but want it to be triggered programmatically, except that I use push segues. Another thing you could try is to call `presentVewController:animated:completion:` on the current view controller and just present the next view controller by creating an instance of it just before the call. When you want the presented view controller to go away, just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried doing the hidden button, which was not working at first. But when I try the function somewhere else it works. So it seems where I am calling it does not have access to the viewcontroller